# Adding more options to 'sort by ' in product listings

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, sorting

I want to add more options in the 'sort by' box. How can I add these and what are other options to add there?

[image]

In this image there are 2 options, Name and Price. How can I add more options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort by other attributes, you have to do make the attribute sortable:

go to *Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes*, select the attribute that you want to add to the "Sort by" menu and set "Used for Sorting in Product Listing" to "Yes":

[image: screenshot]

If this does not work, your theme might have changed the default dropdown. In this case, search for "setAvailableOrders" in the theme layout files and add the following lines below that action:

```
<action method="addOrderToAvailableOrders" translate="label">
    <code>YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE</code>
    <label>YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_LABEL</label>
</action>
```

Comment: It worked through admin  options so didnt try 2nd method. thanks

Answer (score -1):

use this Before that make sure you work on theme don't edit core file 
Sort by High price to low price

```
/app/design/frontend/package/your-theme/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml file
```

Find below code

```
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
</option>
```

Replace into

```
<?php if ($_order != 'Price'): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
</option>
<?php else: ?>
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key) && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->__($_order) . ': Low to High' ?>
</option> 
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key) && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->__($_order) . ': High to Low' ?>
</option> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Sort By Latest Product

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/toolbar.php
```

Find Below code

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
        return $this;
```

Replace into

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
          if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='recentlyadded'){
              $this->_collection->setOrder('entity_id','desc');
          }
          else {
           $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
          }
        }
        return $this;
```

Also replace same this function also in same file
Find

```
public function setDefaultOrder($field)
{
    if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$field])) {
        $this->_orderField = $field;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Replace into

```
public function setDefaultOrder($field) {
    if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$field])) {
        $this->_availableOrder = array(

            'recentlyadded'    => $this->__('Newest Product'),
            'name'        => $this->__('Name'),
            'price'       => $this->__('Price'),
        );
        $this->_orderField = $field;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I havnt tried your method bur will give it try. Thanks for your answer.